# Show that minimum $\text{min}(X_1,..,X_n)$ is geometrically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, probability-distributions, proof-writing

> $X_1,..,X_n$ are linearly independent, identical geometrically
>   distributed random variables with parameter $p \in (0,1)$, i.e. $$P(X_i=k) = p(1-p)^{k-1} \text{ with } k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } i = 1,..,n \text{ and } q = 1-p $$ 
>   Show that the minimum $\text{min}(X_1,..X_n)$ is also geometrically
>   distributed.

They give many hint in task already that why I have ideas. The probability function of $X_i$ is $$f_{X_i}(x) = p(1-p)^x \text{ with } x=0,1,2,3,4,.. \text{ for } i=1,..,n$$

Now survived function from $X_i$ must be $$P(X_i \geq x) = \sum_{i=x}^{\infty}p(1-p)^i$$

Now can change index of sum to start from zero then it look like this:

$$p(1-p)^x \cdot \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^i=p(1-p)^x \cdot \frac{1}{p}= (1-p)^x$$

Now can say that survived function of $Z$ is $S_Z(z) = P(Z \geq z)= P(X_1 \geq z) \cdot P(X_2 \geq z) \cdot ... \cdot P(X_n \geq z)= (1-p)^{nz}$

This is survived function of gemetric random variabel. Now can say that $\text{min}(X_1,..X_n)$ is also geometric distribution? Not know I need make more for show it and is correct?

Scared because maybe I need show that there is same solution for both function and then continue show solution is same for both with induction? Or no need?!

Comment: The proof seems to be correct.

Comment: @MathLover Scared because maybe I need show that there is same solution for both function and then continue show solution is same for both with induction?

Comment: Just FYI, `\min` has its own [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt has all the steps you need. First, the probability distribution of a random variable is unique determined by its survival function.

So all you need is to verify that the survival function of $ \min(X_1,\ldots,X_n) $ is a survival function of a geometrically distributed random variable. That is exactly what you did, more precisely your attempt shows:

$$\min(X_1,\ldots,X_n) \sim Geo(1-(1-p)^n) $$

As a little remark to you: I think, you do not mean "linearly independent", it is just called "independent". Furthermore you work with two different definitions of "geometrically distributed". Be sure that you define the same you use in your proof. (What I mean is:  $\Bbb{P}(X_i = k) $ should be the same as $f_{X_i}(k)$)

Comment: Yes right I don't meaned linearly independent it my bad reflex from old course linear algebra from last year.. I mean independent like you say :) Thank you I make proof correct now all write on paper!!!!